# How to use label names for prometheus alert expression?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to send Prometheus alert if latency is beyond some 100s and based on the Severity label that I passed to gauge metric in instrumentation.

I tried the following

```
- alert: TestAppLatency
  expr:  LATENCY>100 or {{ $labels.SEVERITY }} == 'CRITICAL'
```

But I get the following error

`could not parse expression: 1:32: parse error: unexpected left brace '{'`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `expr` is expected to be a valid promql expression. Here you are using templating syntax. Please clarify your question with what you want to achive; including a sample of the metrics you have would also improve the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
- alert: TestAppLatency
  expr:  LATENCY{SEVERITY="CRITICAL"} > 100
```

Try reading https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/prometheus-alerts for hints.