# Can prometheus.yaml expr contain label in it?

Tags: yaml, prometheus, monitoring, promql

This is a follow up question to this one:
[How to use label names for prometheus alert expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67509274/how-to-use-label-names-for-prometheus-alert-expression)

In this discussion, users offer a way to bypass the need to use the labels in the expr.
However, i have encountered a situation where metrics have a “limit” label and i need to include it in the expr. Is there a valid way to do so?

Comment: As it's mentioned in the comment to linked question,  `expr` of alert rule must contain valid PromQL query. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need the limit from the expr query to be the limit for the alerting rule to trigger

Comment: Generally this is not possible. You can create somewhat similar thing with rather limited support of thresholds, or use a separate metric for thresholds.

Comment: Yes, amazing, thanks!